# How to set a breakpoint for ClickHouse code?

Tags: lldb, clickhouse

I am building ClickHouse like this:

```sh
$ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$(which clang-14) -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++-14) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

Launching debugger

```sh
$ lldb ./clickhouse -- server
Current executable set to '/home/user/ClickHouse/build/programs/clickhouse' (x86_64).
```

Trying to set a breakpoint

```sh
$ breakpoint set --file /home/user/ClickHouse/src/Storages/MergeTree/MergeTreeData.cpp --line 3564
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

But unable to do it. How to set a breakpoint?

Versions:

```
Commit 075bcf3f5fce73f8f554a5c132730d0f79c77707
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
lldb version 10.0.0
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-++20220309053128+569b773323a3-1~exp1~20220309053228.98
cmake version 3.16.3
ninja version 1.10.0
```

Comment: Well, ok, found out how to debug with gdb, it's ok for me. Should be using "directory" command to set directory sources. Maybe lldb has same option

Comment: lldb doesn't require the actual source files to set file & line breakpoints - the line table information is stored in the debug info independent of the content of the source files.  So lldb's equivalent of gdb's "directory" command wouldn't effect setting file & line breakpoints.  It looks more like lldb can't find any debug information.  How does this project generate debug info?

Comment: BTW, you might try setting the breakpoint by just the file name, not the full path.  Sometimes build systems are funny about how they record the path, and just using the file name is a quick way to test that.

Comment: @JimIngham it uses -g -gdwarf-4 flags. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/3517064b6011a33a51457842dc4731e6f729a713/CMakeLists.txt#L372
tried path as just filename, doesn't help

Comment: @JimIngham hm, checked again, it actually does help to pass just a filename, thank you very much!